# Test date value against null value

Tags: php, mysql, date

I like to compare a date (extract from database with a null value (0000-00-00).
I try to do like that:

```
$dateValue = $row_recordset3['ttDateEnvoiDEP'];

if ($dateValue === '0000-00-00') {                  
    $dateEnvoiDEP = "CURRENT_DATE()";                   
}
else {
    $returnOK .= $dateValue;
    $dateEnvoiDEP = $row_recordset3['ttDateEnvoiDEP'];
}
```

But it doesn't work, do you know why?

Comment: 0000-00-00 is clearly not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you do it directly in your `SQL` query, something like this,

```
SELECT   IF(ttDateEnvoiDEP = '0000-00-00', CURDATE(), ttDateEnvoiDEP) 
             as `ttDateEnvoiDEP`,
FROM     ...
WHERE    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

CURRENT_DATE() is a MySQL function, not PHP.

Give this a read: http://php.net/date

Also, if you want to use the current date in that format you can do `date('Y-m-d')` which will return 2012-09-03 or whatever the date is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deal with date with PHP you can use unix time stamp for that.
Read php [time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) and [date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for more information

The problem is your code is you are compareiring 0000-00-00 to $dateValue.0000-00-00 is not null. Not clear what you what here. But I think you want to know if the value is set. so you can try

```
isset($dateValue)
```

Hope this could help you!

EDIT:

```
if(!isset($dateValue)){
    $dateEnvoiDEP = time();
}else{
//do other stuff
}
```